Android: ImageAnalysis giving lower resolution as compared to Image Capture
I am using cameraX in my android app for imageCapturing.
Imagecapture giving full resolution i.e 3000 x 4000 but ImageAnalysis is only giving 1080 x 1440.
Here is my code:
private ResolutionSelector resolutionSelector; 

resolutionSelector = new ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                .setAllowedResolutionMode(ResolutionSelector.PREFER_HIGHER_RESOLUTION_OVER_CAPTURE_RATE)  
                .setResolutionStrategy(ResolutionStrategy.HIGHEST_AVAILABLE_STRATEGY)
                .build();

imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelector)
                .build();

ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelector)
                        .build();

I want full resolution image after Image analysis because the app requires full resolution image. With lesser resolution the app gives degraded image quality.

Is there any way to match the resolution in cameraX?

What else can we use to achieve the same if totally not possible from CameraX?


Thanks in advance .

ImageCapture usually supports higher resolution than ImageAnalysis. For details see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice
I am curious why do you need the resolution to match. Are you trying to locate a detected object in ImageCapture? If so, you can transform the coordinates of the detected object.
